# Excel table work (2 sets of data -> a single set)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want a table with two sets of data on columns to be reaaranged into a single set obtained by interlancing the initial sets, as in figure.

[image: data table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula - if you have Excel 365:

```
=LET(d,A1:D10,
VSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(d,1,2),CHOOSECOLS(d,3,4)))
```

You have to adjust the source of `d`

--- edit
This formula will do a true Interlanced - without expecting the second column to be in descending order:

```
=LET(d,A1:D4,
colA,HSTACK(DROP(d,,-2),ROW(d)),
colB,HSTACK(DROP(d,,2),ROW(d)),
DROP(SORT(VSTACK(colA,colB),3),,-1))
```

[image]

Comment: tell me what is d: cell range?

Comment: Within the `LET` formula: first part `d, A1:D10` --> you have to update the cell range according to your sheet.

Comment: I have replaced "," with ";", It worked but they arent INTERLANCED

Comment: I added a new formula - it doesn't depend on the second column but does a "true" interlance

Comment: Actually all sets sorted together is what i really need, first formula is preffered. Thanks. I have use it and it solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the following formula :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A13</kbd>

```
=LET(α,A1:D10,
SORT(VSTACK(TAKE(α,,2),DROP(α,,2)),2))
```

---

Or, a compact, sleek and shorter alternative using <kbd>WRAPROWS()</kbd> & <kbd>TOCOL()</kbd>:

[image]

---

```
=WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A1:D10),2)
```

---